# Input data in psql from mongo created object

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, postgresql

I'm entering in my db the _id from mongo but the answer is strange and when i

> console.log(createdPlace._id);

i get a regular answer

> 5f43b0fdc9d92c05282360a8

```js
const addTodo = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { content } = req.body;

  const createdPlace = new Url({
    content: content,
    enable: false,
  });
  // Sending it To Mongo
  try {
    console.log(createdPlace._id);
    await createdPlace.save();
    await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO todo (todo_id ,content, enable) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)",
      [createdPlace._id, content, false]
    );
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError("Creating Place fails");
    return next(error);
  }

  res.sendStatus(200);
};
```

The output from the db is

```js
  {
    "todo_id": "\"5f43b0fdc9d92c05282360a8\"",
    "content": "first sending to with sasasddaame id",
    "enable": false
  }
```

that's making me crazy this "\"  \"" at the end of the todo_id hope for help.

Comment: You want to save in PSQL your MongoDb collection?

Comment: both of them, my probleme is this "\"5f43b0fdc9d92c05282360a8\"", Why there is this ""